# Как ограничить вводимые значения и вывести табличку с ними? Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно, что-бы при запуске кода выводилась (желательно) табличка со значениями "4" и "12"

Comment: ну, допустим. спасибо, что поделились...

Comment: `print('|4|12|')`

Comment: Нет, мне нужно что-бы можно было вводить только 4 или 12

Answer (score 3):

```
x = input("Введите 4 или 12 ")
if x != "4" and x != "12":
    while x != "4" and x != "12":
        x = input("Недопустимое значение. Введите 4 или 12 ")
```

Comment: используйте более питоновский подход, сохранив допустимые значения в последовательности, и проверкой `if value not in sequense:`. У вас сократится код и будет много более понятно

Comment: Гляньте на мой ответ, вот это я имел в виду

Answer (score 2):

Ответ больше, чтобы показать, что я имел в виду в комментарии к первому ответу

```py
access = ("4", "12")

while True:
    print("You can type either 4 or 12")
    i = input()
    if i in access:
        break

print(i)
```